# Difference between Controller and Request params

Tags: grails, controller, request

I notice in Grails controllers, there is a params Object in the Controller and a params object on the request.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` in controllers is defined in [GetParamsDynamicProperty](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/metaclass/GetParamsDynamicProperty.java) as:

```
paramsMap = new GrailsParameterMap(request);
```

`request.params` is defined in [GrailsWebRequest](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsWebRequest.java) as:

```
if (originalParams == null) {
    originalParams = new GrailsParameterMap(getCurrentRequest());
}
params = (GrailsParameterMap)originalParams.clone();
```

Both are created from the current request and should contain the same data.

Answer (score 2):

`params` in controller is a property (viz, `getParams()`) in Grails Controller Artefact which represents the request parameters as a `mutable` HashMap, which gives the flexibility to get modified in the app.

In contrast to [request.getParameterMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29), which gives you an immutable map and you cannot modify it as you do in params.

Being said that, I suppose you were referring to `parameterMap` instead of `params` in `request`. :)